# R arules - apply old itemsets to new transaction data

Tags: r, arules

I've generated a list of frequent itemsets from a relatively small transaction list using arules´ apriori algorithm. I also calculated the lift for each of these itemsets.

```
itemsets <- apriori(data=TransMat, parameter=list(supp=0.1, maxlen=4, target="frequent itemsets"))

quality(itemsets)$lift <- interestMeasure(itemsets, measure="lift", trans = TransMat)
```

Now I get a new, very long (!) list of transactions.
Instead of calculating new itemsets from the new list of transactions I want to apply the old `itemsets` to the new transaction list.

Or in other words: I want to calculate support and lift for each of my old rules based on the new transactions. How can that be done?

(Remark: If possible I would like to avoid calculating a new set of rules for the new list of transaction in the process, since that list is so massive.)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer can be found in the arules documentation. Even though it is somehow hidden in the `interestMeasure` function. That function can calculate interest measures for old rules/itemsets on new transactions.

```
interestMeasure(rules_old, c("support"), transactions = TransactionMatrix_new, reuse = FALSE)
```